# Can a Google/Samsung backup be restored if the account holder is not logged in?

Tags: security, backup, restore, google-backup

I am concerned about security on an old phone that I have given away, after resetting it.  Smart lock won't  make any difference, as it only applies to my home location.

Comment: Please elaborate on your concerns, Are you worried that your Google Account will still be linked to that device ? .. If so, you can remove the device from your Google account prior to factory reset with this link https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup  and for recent device removal have a look here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en-GB ... if none of these help then look at this for all linked devices https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7552681?hl=en

Comment: Thank you very much, Zillinium, for your helpful advice. I used the first link to remove the device from my Google account, although I no longer have the phone, and also removed permissions given to apps I had previously uninstalled on my present phone that I had believed to be reversed when they were uninstalled.

Comment: @Zillinium Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this would answer the question so it's purpose was purely a comment, I'll repost it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the device from your Google account prior to factory reset with this link [Google's Security Checkup Page](https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup)  and for recent device removal have a look here [Google's Recent Devices Page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en-GB) ... if none of these help then look at this for all linked devices [Google's Support for Linked Devices](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7552681?hl=en)